# How to handle Excel MIME type $format=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet support in OData olingo Java's lib processor?

Tags: excel, odata, olingo

I wrote OData Service with Olingo V4 and SpringBoot application.

Is there any code snippet in Java that demonstrates how to handle Excel data format in an OData processor using Apache Olingo libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Media Entities` to process binary data. This will require implementation of `MediaEntityProcessor` in Olingo, under which you can handle different types of Content-Types.

Please refer to this tutorial for reference.
https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/media/tutorial_media.html#implement-the-interface-mediaentityprocessor